# How specify proxy in Katalon programically?

Tags: unit-testing, katalon-studio

I am have list of proxies and I need repeat one test through every proxy. How to specify proxy in Katalon programically? I havent found any groovy methods for this is Katalon documentation. 
Maybe I can specify proxy in Katalon using command string options? Then I can write programm that execute katalon for every proxy, but i dont find this command string options in docs

Answer (score 0):

Katalon Studio version 5.3.1 has supported passing proxy settings to console mode command. It is not yet available to set proxy settings from test script.